# Cannot access a disposed object on Program.cs Main method

Tags: c#, winforms, objectdisposedexception

I have a `WinForm` application with two different forms. If the first command line argument is *"download"*, the `Download` form should appear. I get an `ObjectDisposedException` on the `Application.Run(new Download(args));` line on the `Main` method of my program.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args.Length > 0)
            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "download":
                    if (args.Length == 4)
                        Application.Run(new Download(args));
                    break;
                default:
                    Application.Run(new ApsisRunner(args));
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**
Exception stack trace

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at ApsisCampaignRunner.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\pedram.mobedi\Documents\GitHub\Postbag\ApsisCampaignRunner\Program.cs:line 31
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Does it say what the disposed object is?

Comment: This may be due to your Main method exiting before the Download dialog is initialised. Or is Run() a blocking call in WinForms?  The parent app may be calling Dispose() on it before it appears.

Comment: @OmriAharon I added a screenshot.

Comment: Can you try to change your project to a Console Application?

Comment: @olitee This is the entry point to the program, so how is it possible for Main method exist before the Download dialog is initialized. Or, I mean, how can I make sure of that? I am running this app with command line arguments, so I don't understand what the role of the parent app is here.

Comment: The problem can occur anywhere in your application, can you post the exception call stack

Comment: It's possible if the Application.Run method does not block, which is why I asked. It might be helpful to know exactly which object is throwing the disposed exception. Can you look at the exception details and let us know? Is it the Application or Download object ... Or something else?

Comment: @olitee Application.Run is a blocking call

Comment: @Console I added the stack trace at the end of the question.

Comment: @It's the `Download` object that is triggering the exception.

Comment: My guess is you the form is open for edit in a visual tool and somehow the controls are in some funky state. Wild guess. Restart your Visual C#..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you doing something like this one in the Constructor of Download form?

[image]

The problem might be in code of Download Form. You should not close or dispose Form in the constructor.

Comment: Yes I am! I am using `this.Close()`!

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is fine, but if a object disposed exception occures anywhere inside your Download class it is thrown up the call stack until where you see it (the main method),

The cause is that you try to set your form visible after you disposed it.

You can try to break on ObjectDisposed Exceptions and find the exact line it is thrown, you can do so under Debug -> Exceptions.

Comment: I do not have a background thread in my `Download` form yet. But in my `ApsisRunner` form which will be run if the first command line argument is not a string that is "download", I am using `BackgroundWorker`s.